# An appropriate statistic for a between-group design of single-case data

Tags: nonparametric

I am hoping to gain some insight into potential statistical tests I can use on a data set that involves single-case designs but also between-group comparisons.  I am a behavior analyst typically rely on visual inspection of data and am unfamiliar with the statistical measures appropriate to single-subject data.

Below is an image of hypothetical data for two participants:

[image: Hypothetical Data for Minimal-Training (Control) and Enhanced-Training (Experimental)]

In this study, I am evaluating the persistence of appropriate behavior (open circles) and relapse of inappropriate behavior (closed circles) that occurs in the third phase labeled EXT.  In addition, I believe that the rate of change in appropriate and inappropriate behavior during the second phase (DRA) will be quicker for the Enhanced-Training group.

I have seen some articles in our flagship journal use nonparametric tests such as Mann-Whitney and Wilcoxon Rank Sum Test.  I was wondering whether either of those tests would be appropriate for my analyses or if there are more appropriate measures. I apologize for my lack of understanding, but I hope someone may be kind enough to help guide me in the right direction.